# i tried to run map reduce sample program for hadoop-1.1.2. but i have following error

Tags: hadoop

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.  

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority:  localhost:54311
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:490)  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:513)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530) 
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

please any one help me

Comment: I think there is some kind of configuration issue in your mapred-site.xml file. Can you please paste the contents of your mapred-site.xml file?

Comment: hi rohit, thanks for ur answer. i pasted content for mapred-site.xml file.but the same issue has repeated. this is my pasted content <property>
<name>
mapred.job.tracker
</name>
<value>
localhost:54311
</value>
<description>
The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
at. If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
and reduce task.
</description>
</property>

Answer (score 0):

Check that every proccess is up by running "jps". The jobtracker must be up and appear in the list of your localhost computer

- Namenode
- **Jobtracker**
- Tasktracker
- Datanode
- SecondaryNamenode

If it is not up it might be that another proccess is using the same port (54311) or simply a firewall problem

I hope it helps